# How can I conditional join two tables to get results based on an evaluation (SQL Server)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I have two tables in my database:

*Offices*

```
id       Department         Section       PositionID         
-------------------------------------------------------
1    |   DataCenter   |    Developer  |       10     
2    |   DataCenter   |    DBA        |       11     
3    |   DataCenter   |    SA         |       12     
4    |   DataCenter   |    HelpDesk   |       13     
5    |   DataCenter   |    DepHead    |       14
6    |   Produce      |    Stocker    |       19
7    |   Produce      |    Farmer     |       20
```

*Positions*

```
id        PosName         OfficeID       Level         
-------------------------------------------------------
10    |  Senior Dev   |       1     |     1     
11    |  Senior DBA   |       2     |     1 
12    |  Senior SA    |       3     |     1 
13    |  Help Desk    |       4     |     2 
14    |  Supervisor   |       1     |     0
15    |  Junior Dev   |       1     |     2
16    |  Junior Dev   |       3     |     2
17    |  Junior DBA   |       2     |     2
18    |  Junior DBA   |       2     |     2
19    |  Junior DBA   |       2     |     2
20    |  Junior SA    |       1     |     2
```

How can I select all entries from Positions based on their Department and Section, but one above their level? I'm guessing I need a join with some kind of condition that gets evaluated to do this.

For example, the Senior Dev position is at level 1. So, I would like for the two Junior Dev positions at level 2 to grouped with it. By the same token, the three level 2 Junior DBA positions would be associated with the Senior DBA position. And the trickiest part would be to get ALL the positions in the DataCenter associated with the Supervisor (who is at level 0).

My end goal is to use this query in a web page where users assigned to a position can only see users who work under them and in their section/department.

So perhaps the end query result might look something like this:

```
Department      Section        ManagingPosition         Position        PositionID
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DataCenter   | Developer  |      Senior Dev       |   Junior Dev   |       15    
DataCenter   | Developer  |      Senior Dev       |   Junior Dev   |       16    
DataCenter   | DBA        |      Senior DBA       |   Junior DBA   |       17    
DataCenter   | DBA        |      Senior DBA       |   Junior DBA   |       18   
DataCenter   | DBA        |      Senior DBA       |   Junior DBA   |       19    
DataCenter   | SA         |      Senior SA        |   Junior SA    |       20   
DataCenter   | DepHead    |      Supervisor       |   Junior Dev   |       15
DataCenter   | DepHead    |      Supervisor       |   Junior Dev   |       16
DataCenter   | DepHead    |      Supervisor       |   Junior DBA   |       17
DataCenter   | DepHead    |      Supervisor       |   Junior DBA   |       18
DataCenter   | DepHead    |      Supervisor       |   Junior DBA   |       19
DataCenter   | DepHead    |      Supervisor       |   Junior SA    |       20
DataCenter   | DepHead    |      Supervisor       |   Help Desk    |       13
```

So far, I have

```sql
SELECT
    O.Department,
    O.Section,
    O.Position AS ManagingPosition,
    P.PosName AS Position,
    P.PositionID
FROM
    Offices O
    INNER JOIN Positions P on O.PositionID = P.id
```

I know this is incorrect, though. What's the best way to query these tables to get the results I want? I can also modify these tables (add columns) to get results as well. I appreciate any help!

Edit:

For clarification, the Levels in the Positions table start with level 0 being the highest, and level 2 being the lowest. So level 0 should be able to see anything greater (i.e. level 1 and 2), and level 1 should only be able to see level 2.

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3). "A" is not for Officers, nor is "B" for Positions. "O" and "P" would be *far* better choices.

Comment: with this design , its not clear which position is the higher level of other position, so you need a new column like "managerpositinId" to assign a manager to each position, otherwise there is no way to find out

Comment: You should have another column in Positions table. something like ParentPositionId to know who is under a position.

Comment: @Larnu, you're right. It's definitely something I should do a better job with - thanks for keeping me in line! I went ahead and updated my post.

Comment: @eshirvana, apologies for the lack of clarity. The lower the number, the higher the level of the position is. I edited my post as well to improve the clarity. I'll look into the managerpositionId column idea as well. Thanks!

Comment: @ByronAlex thanks for your suggestion! I do like the idea, but how would this look as far as a query? As an example, for Senior DBA it would be easy enough - just an inner join on Positions1.ParentPositionId = Positions2.Id or something like that. But what about in the case of the supervisor?

Comment: @nightmare637 Ok, let me create the query to show you how.

Comment: @nightmare637 I posted as an answer, I hope this works for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to add a column to define the parent position for each position.

[image]

And then an option is recursion with CTE (https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-recursive-cte/)

```
WITH PositionsCTE ( PositionID, ManagingPosition, Position, OfficeId, [Level])
AS
(   
    --starts with the very first level 
    SELECT
        id as PositionID, cast('' as varchar(50)) as ManagingPosition,
        PosName, OfficeId, [Level]
    FROM Positions 
    WHERE ParentId IS NULL -- (supervisor in this case)
    UNION ALL
    -- and then recursivity 
    SELECT
        p.id as PositionID, Pcte.Position as ManagingPosition,
        p.PosName, p.OfficeId, p.[Level]
    FROM Positions AS p
    INNER JOIN PositionsCTE Pcte ON p.ParentId = Pcte.PositionID
)
Select 
    o.Department,
    o.Section, 
    p.ManagingPosition,
    p.Position,
    p.PositionID
from Offices o
inner join PositionsCTE p on o.id = p.OfficeId;
```